# How to cite a speech only available as a YouTube-video

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I created a paragraph about Project Soli which was introduced at this year's Google I/O conference. However there are only two videos available.
This is one of them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpbWQbkl8_g

How would you cite this speech and put it in the bibliography?

Comment: Biblatex  has an `online` entry type.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With package `biblatex`, you can cite online entries (`@online`) without anything to care about. All entry fields support an `url` field as well.

Remember, you can even refer to a very specific moment by appending the time to the youtube link.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @online{youtube,
        title = {Some cool motion sensor stuff},
        date = {2015},
        organization = {Youtube},
        author = {Peter Zatko and  Ivan Poupyrev and  Rachid El
        Guerrab and  Regina Dugan},
        url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpbWQbkl8_g#t=20m15s},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{youtube}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: hedgeBiblatexYoutube]

* links hidden for the screenshot

Comment: How would you reference a movie?

Comment: @nilon depends. If it is only one,  i would misuse  book or online; if you have several,  i would define a new driver.

Comment: Yes @Johannes_B. But what would you put after the `@` such as "book", could you use something like "movie" or "film"?

Comment: @nilon yes. But you need to define a driver for it.

Comment: that seems like a good idea. How do you do that?

Comment: @nilon look at the documentation or ask a new question. It is off-topic for this Q/A

Comment: What about multiple citations referring to the same video, but at different times? How do you cite the video timestamp reference (like page references) in each account in the text?

Comment: @Magne I guess you would use a comment.

Comment: I found out a nice way: `\cite[at~11:27]{kleinyoutube2014}`

Answer (score 8):

```
@Misc{Zatko15,
  author =   {Peiter Zatko and Ivan Poupyrev and
                  El Guerrab, Rachid and Regina Dugan},
  title =    {{G}oogle {I/O} 2015. {A} little badass. 
                  {B}eautiful. {T}ech and human. {W}ork and love. {ATAP}},
  howpublished = {\url{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpbWQbkl8_g}},
  month =    {May},
  day =          29,
  year =     2015
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe add, that this approach is only useful for the older BibTeX/bst system? Or in other words, can you add that this is not good with `biblatex`?

Comment: @Johannes_B Why is that? What would be good with `biblatex`?

Comment: I think there are better ways with `biblatex`, but I wouldn't say this is bad.